# Drop down menu css align right

Tags: html, css

I wrote the code after W3schools tutorial and it works great but
I've ried various combinations of `float:left`, `position:relative`, but couldn't figure it out.

My question it's: how I have to change the CSS proprieties in that way that will result a second level menu that will open in the right of his parent, not under like it's right now.
You can see the second level menu when you open "Projects" element.
Here is the menu https://jsfiddle.net/Anaramia/mw4u2wtu/

**CSS**

```
.mainMenubackground {
    background-color: #37459D;
    width: 100%;
}
.mainMenu {
    font-family: 'Kadwa', serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    min-width: 250%;
}
.submenu {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a,
.dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 38px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}
li a:hover,
dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #798AF7;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
li:hover ul {
    /* when list items are hovered over, do this to lists contained within them... */
    
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #37459D;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #303d70), color-stop(100%, #a6acd4));
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}
.dropdown-content a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    border-top: 0 none;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #37459D;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    diplay: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use position: relative (instead of absolute) for the .dropdown-content and change display: block to display: inline-block on li:hover ul

```
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

    li:hover ul {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #37459D;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #303d70), color-stop(100%, #a6acd4));
        opacity: 0.9;
        filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    }
```

EDIT:
Maybe this is close to something what you need:
https://jsfiddle.net/mw4u2wtu/14/

Comment: Thank you for your time and help but it doesn't work. The position must be "absolute", other way the hole menu is floating when I put the mouse over it. Only the second level menu from Project (Echidinas and Platypus) I need to pop-up in the right of their parents (Current and Previous)

Comment: I am not sure what you really want to do. If you want to show the second level menu on the right side of its parent you need to move other elements to make some space.

Comment: [What I have][1]


[What I'm looking for][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cHzR6.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hzNIJ.png

Comment: I see, you want to put 3rd level to the right of the 2nd level

Comment: Yes. Misunderstanding language. Sorry

Comment: Okey, I think this is the correct solution. Please review this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/mw4u2wtu/14/